# Why Youtube trhows a NullPointerException when trying to get the editlink

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

```
String atomXml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
"<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:fields='yt:accessControl' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>" +
"<yt:accessControl action='comment' permission='denied'/>"+
"<yt:accessControl action='rate' permission='denied'/></entry>";
System.out.println("Dsiabling Comments and Rating");
GDataRequest request = service.createPatchRequest(new URL(entry.getEditLink().getHref()));
request.getRequestStream().write(atomXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
request.execute();
System.out.println("Dsiabling Comments and Rating COMPLETED");
```

In the above code entry is a VideoEntry which was retuned by uploading a video to YouTube. But when I try the code it throws a null pointer exception. Any fix for this. And If there is any other way of setting the comments and rating disabled its fine as well. I do the following once the Video is published.

Answer (score 0):

```
String updateUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/"+videoId;    
VideoEntry _entry = service.getEntry(new URL(updateUrl), VideoEntry.class);
VideoEntry vToDel = service.getEntry(new URL(_entry.getEditLink().getHref()), VideoEntry.class);
vToDel.delete();
```

If you want to delete or update a video you cannot take it directly from edit link of the uploaded VideoEntry. You need to query for a new video entry using the same video id. And use that to update or delete.